# Using getline with a global variable

Tags: c, getline

I'll read several lines of text, so I want to keep it in a global variable. I did such a thing:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static char currentLine[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

static bool readNextLine(void)
{
    return getline(&currentLine, NULL, stdin);
}
```

An error I get is

```
cc -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -O2 -MD -MP -Wall -Werror -c src/parse.c -o build/parse.o
src/parse.c: In function ‘readNextLine’:
src/parse.c:14:20: error: passing argument 1 of ‘getline’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
     return getline(&currentLine, NULL, stdin);
                    ^
In file included from src/parse.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:678:20: note: expected ‘char ** restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[100000]’
 extern _IO_ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: man getline: `If  *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program.  (In this case, the  value in *n is ignored.) Alternatively,  before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.` TL;DR: You can't do that.

Comment: Passing a wrong type to `getline` that's why you get an error . A pointer to pointe and a pointer to array both are different .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline(&currentLine, NULL, stdin);` expect to manipulate 2 things: a `char *` to allocated memory and a size of type `size_t`.  So the address to both these items needs to be passed.  The below code fails as `getline()` cannot change the address of `currentLine[]` and neither is it allocated.

```
char currentLine[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
getline(&currentLine, NULL, stdin); // fails
```

Instead

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char *currentLine = NULL;
static size_t currentLineSize = 0;

// true when a line is read
static bool readNextLine(void) {
    return getline(&currentLine, &currentLineSize, stdin) >= 0;
}
```

Note: Robust code would perform a final `free()` after the final use of the buffer.

```
static void readNextLine_CleanUp(void) {
    free(currentLine);
    currentLine = NULL;
    currentLineSize = 0;
}
```

[Ref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use correct type for the variable and use [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) correctly.

- The first argument have to be a pointer to a pointer to `char`.
- The second argument cannot be `NULL`.
- Use the return value correctly to tell whether the call was successful.

corrcted code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static char *currentLine = NULL;

static bool readNextLine(void)
{
    size_t dummy = 0;
    free(currentLine);
    currentLine = NULL;
    return getline(&currentLine, &dummy, stdin) >= 0;
}
```